# Unresolved External Symbol - Only in Release mode

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, visual-c++-6, unresolved-external

I'm using Visual C++ 6, and my application builds and runs fine in debug mode, but I get these two Unresolved External Symbol errors when trying to build in Release mode:

```
OverUnderReportDoc.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual int     __thiscall COverUnderReportDoc::GenerateReport(void)" (? GenerateReport@COverUnderReportDoc@@UAEHXZ)

OverUnderReportDoc.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual bool __thiscall COverUnderReportDoc::DoReport(void)" (?DoReport@COverUnderReportDoc@@UAE_NXZ)
```

COverUnderReportDoc is a class derived from CReportDoc, which is derived from CDocument, part of the MFC framework.

Here are the function declarations:

```
public:

virtual int GenerateReport(void);
virtual bool DoReport(void);
```

And the definitions:

```
bool COverUnderReportDoc::DoReport(void)
{

// Instantiate the dialog
CCriteriaDlg dlg;
m_Report.BreakSpace(FALSE);

// Get a pointer to the window
CWnd* pWnd = AfxGetApp()->m_pMainWnd;

// When OK is clicked...
if (dlg.DoModal() == IDOK)
{       
    // Set the document title
    SetTitle("Inventory Over/Under");

    // Copy some values from the dialog to member variables

    GenerateReport();

    pWnd->ShowWindow(SW_MAXIMIZE);

}
else
{
            // If Cancel is clicked, close the program
    if(pWnd)
        pWnd->PostMessage(WM_CLOSE);
    return false;
}

return true;
}

int COverUnderReportDoc::GenerateReport(void)
{

// write the headers to the report
// if there was no problem
if (DoHeaders())
{
    // assemble the report data
    // if that went well
    if (ScanFile())
        // write the summary to the report
        DoSummary();
}
// return the document status
return m_nStatus;
}
```

I'm really not sure how to resolve this, those methods aren't in any libraries, and the class compiles fine, so I don't know why it doesn't see them while linking. Anyone have any ideas?

**EDIT:** Here are my project options:

**Release Project Options:**

(`C/C++` tab of `Project Settings`)

```
/nologo /Zp1 /MD /W3 /GX /O2 /D "WIN32" /D "NDEBUG" /D "_WINDOWS" /D "_AFXDLL" /D   "_MBCS" /D "BTI_WIN_32" /FR"Release/" /Fo"Release/" /Fd"Release/" /FD /c
```

(`Link` tab of `Project Settings`)

```
MYLIB.lib w3btrv7.lib VERSION.LIB /nologo /subsystem:windows /incremental:no /pdb:"Release/OverUnderReport.pdb" /machine:I386 /out:"Release/OverUnderReport.exe"
```

**Debug Project options:**

(`C/C++` tab of `Project Settings`)

```
/nologo /Zp1 /MDd /W3 /GX /ZI /Ot /D "WIN32" /D "_DEBUG" /D "_WINDOWS" /D "_AFXDLL" /D "_MBCS" /D "BTI_WIN_32" /FR"Debug/" /Fo"Debug/" /Fd"Debug/" /FD /GZ /c
```

(`Link` tab of `Project Settings`)

```
VERSION.LIB MYLIB.lib w3btrv7.lib /nologo /subsystem:windows /profile /debug /machine:I386 /out:"Debug/OverUnderReport.exe"
```

Comment: Usually the reason for something not working between debug and release builds is configuration settings and/or compiler optimizations. Also did you publicly inherit from `CReportDoc` ?  `COverUnderReportDoc : public CReportDoc`

Comment: Yes, `COverUnderReportDoc` publicly inherits from `CReportDoc`. I'll add my project options to the original post as well, as I really don't know what I'm looking at/for with those...

Comment: Out of curiousity,have you performed a clean and then build?

Comment: Yes, but the Linking error remains.

Comment: Check what `.obj` files exist in the `Debug` directory and compare with those that exist in the `Release` directory. Do the same files exist (they will differ in size).

Comment: All the `.obj`'s in the `Debug` folder have a corresponding `.obj` in the `Release` folder.

Comment: Could you post the source file where `bool COverUnderReportDoc::DoReport(void)` is defined?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Line #102 at pastebin.com/e1E0WcBT :

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
```

results in skipping all definitions of member functions from that point when built in release mode.

Comment: Just saw that and corrected it after I posted it to Pastebin, all is working fine now. Thanks for the help!